# Data Dump- Tags missing from internet archive torrent

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I have downloaded the data dump of stack overflow and I am trying to find a link between users and tags.
For example : https://stackoverflow.com/users/446515/vache?tab=tags
this person has 276 tags and each one is associated with non-wiki questions and non-wiki answers.
    189 c# × 65
Yet in the readme file there is no such info and not even tags. Any idea what is wrong?

**READ ME:**

> - Format: 7zipped
> - Files:
>
>   - **badges**.xml
>
>     - UserId, e.g.: "420"
>     - Name, e.g.: "Teacher"
>     - Date, e.g.: "2008-09-15T08:55:03.923"
>   - **comments**.xml
>
>     - Id
>     - PostId
>     - Score
>     - Text, e.g.: "@Stu Thompson: Seems possible to me - why not try it?"
>     - CreationDate, e.g.:"2008-09-06T08:07:10.730"
>     - UserId
>   - **posts**.xml
>
>     - Id
>     - PostTypeId
>
>       - 1: Question
>       - 2: Answer
>     - ParentID (only present if PostTypeId is 2)
>     - AcceptedAnswerId (only present if PostTypeId is 1)
>     - CreationDate
>     - Score
>     - ViewCount
>     - Body
>     - OwnerUserId
>     - LastEditorUserId
>     - LastEditorDisplayName="Jeff Atwood"
>     - LastEditDate="2009-03-05T22:28:34.823"
>     - LastActivityDate="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480"
>     - CommunityOwnedDate="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480"
>     - ClosedDate="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480"
>     - Title=
>     - Tags=
>     - AnswerCount
>     - CommentCount
>     - FavoriteCount
>   - **posthistory**.xml
>
>     - Id
>     - PostHistoryTypeId
>
>       - 1: Initial Title - The first title a question is asked with.
>       - 2: Initial Body - The first raw body text a post is submitted with.
>       - 3: Initial Tags - The first tags a question is asked with.
>       - 4: Edit Title - A question's title has been changed.
>       - 5: Edit Body - A post's body has been changed, the raw text is stored here as markdown.
>       - 6: Edit Tags - A question's tags have been changed.
>       - 7: Rollback Title - A question's title has reverted to a previous version.
>       - 8: Rollback Body - A post's body has reverted to a previous version - the raw text is stored here.
>       - 9: Rollback Tags - A question's tags have reverted to a previous version.
>       - 10: Post Closed - A post was voted to be closed.
>       - 11: Post Reopened - A post was voted to be reopened.
>       - 12: Post Deleted - A post was voted to be removed.
>       - 13: Post Undeleted - A post was voted to be restored.
>       - 14: Post Locked - A post was locked by a moderator.
>       - 15: Post Unlocked - A post was unlocked by a moderator.
>       - 16: Community Owned - A post has become community owned.
>       - 17: Post Migrated - A post was migrated.
>       - 18: Question Merged - A question has had another, deleted question merged into itself.
>       - 19: Question Protected - A question was protected by a moderator
>       - 20: Question Unprotected - A question was unprotected by a moderator
>       - 21: Post Disassociated - An admin removes the OwnerUserId from a post.
>       - 22: Question Unmerged - A previously merged question has had its answers and votes restored.
>     - PostId
>     - RevisionGUID: At times more than one type of history record can be recorded by a single action.  All of these will be grouped using the
>         same RevisionGUID
>     - CreationDate: "2009-03-05T22:28:34.823"
>     - UserId
>     - UserDisplayName: populated if a user has been removed and no longer referenced by user Id
>     - Comment: This field will contain the comment made by the user who edited a post
>     - Text: A raw version of the new value for a given revision
>
>       - If PostHistoryTypeId = 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, or 15  this column will contain a JSON encoded string with all users who have voted for
>           the PostHistoryTypeId
>       - If PostHistoryTypeId = 17 this column will contain migration details of either "from " or "to "
>     - CloseReasonId
>
>       - 1: Exact Duplicate - This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with
>           another identical question.
>       - 2: off-topic
>       - 3: subjective
>       - 4: not a real question
>       - 7: too localized
>   - **postlinks**.xml
>
>     - Id
>     - CreationDate
>     - PostId
>     - RelatedPostId
>     - PostLinkTypeId
>     - 1: Linked
>     - 3: Duplicate
>   - **users**.xml
>
>     - Id
>     - Reputation
>     - CreationDate
>     - DisplayName
>     - EmailHash
>     - LastAccessDate
>     - WebsiteUrl
>     - Location
>     - Age
>     - AboutMe
>     - Views
>     - UpVotes
>     - DownVotes
>   - **votes**.xml
>
>     - Id
>     - PostId
>     - VoteTypeId
>     - `1`: AcceptedByOriginator
>     - `2`: UpMod
>     - `3`: DownMod
>     - `4`: Offensive
>     - `5`: Favorite - if VoteTypeId = 5 UserId will be populated
>     - `6`: Close
>     - `7`: Reopen
>     - `8`: BountyStart
>     - `9`: BountyClose
>     - `10`: Deletion
>     - `11`: Undeletion
>     - `12`: Spam
>     - `13`: InformModerator
>     - CreationDate
>     - UserId (only for VoteTypeId 5)
>     - BountyAmount (only for VoteTypeId 9)

Comment: You'd extract those counts yourself; pair up users and their posts, then count the tags found on the posts.

Comment: yes but since the tags are part of the schema [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), why are they not available in the first place?

Comment: Ah, interesting; it does appear that a few tables are missing then. They won't contain per-person tag counts though.